# Не работает vertical-align: middle;

Tags: html, css

Вот смотрите, простой казалось бы код, но почему не работает vertical-align: middle;?

```
.mainHistory{
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;

}
.cellHistory{
     float: left; 
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
.cellHistory span{
        display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}



  <div class="mainHistory">
  <div class="cellHistory">
    <span>01 01 2000</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="cellHistory">
    <span>Создание фирмы
    Первоначальное название: ооо фирма </span>
  </div>  
  <div class="cellHistory">
    <img src="/1.png">

  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо так

```css
.mainHistory {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 100px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0; <! -- убираем отступы  display: inline-block -->       
}
.cellHistory {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.cellHistory span {}
```

```html
<div class="mainHistory">
  <div class="cellHistory">
    <span>01 01 2000</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="cellHistory">
    <span>Создание фирмы Первоначальное название: ооо фирма</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cellHistory">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x250" alt="" />
  </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vvt6nq4/)

Comment: круто Вы сделали, а почему Вы приняли решение,  вытащить из span и поставить vertical-align в .cellHistory? на встроенный элемент плохо действует это свойство?